# Laravel .htaccess with forced HTTPS

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I use this .htaccess file in root directory of my Laravel website on hosting, so the visitors dont see /public/ in URL address:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

But so far I couldnt find a simple solution to add forced HTTPS redirection. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What has this got to do with Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Force domain to use https using .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your .htaccess with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you
You should try below in .htaccess

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]